# How to register snapshot directory in Amazon Elasticsearch Service using .net SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-sdk, nest, elasticsearch-net

I want to create repository to S3 from Amazon ES using .net SDK.
But I could not find any methods, sample codes and articles to do that.

Perhaps Is it no implemeneted in .net SDK?

Comment: I believe you would use the Elasticsearch API to perform this, not the AWS SDK. Similar to how you would use an ODBC driver to connect to an RDS database and perform queries, not the AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

[Install the AWS Cloud plugin on each Elasticsearch node in your cluster](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws) and follow the information given for generic configuration and EC2 permissions. To create an s3 repository with NEST would be

```
client.CreateRepository("respository-name", c => c
    .S3(s3 => s3
        .Settings("bucket-name", s => s
            .Region("us-west")
        )
    )
);
```

and to save a snapshot to the repository

```
client.Snapshot("repository-name", "snapshot-name", s => s
    .WaitForCompletion(false)
    .Index("index-name")
);
```

[All parameters for snapshot API are exposed in NEST.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html)